# Pgfplots Scientific Notation 2^x

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, pgfplotstable, graphs

I am plotting a logarithmic graph and since the values are relatively large, pgfplots is outputting the values in the y-axis in terms of 10<sup>x</sup>
. However, I'd like to output it the format 2<sup>x</sup>.

I read the documentation but it's not very clear in terms of how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

A code snippet for my graph is shown below:

```latex
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymin = 0, scale only axis, height=5cm,
                width=\textwidth, legend pos=north west, xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$k$, width=\textwidth]
            \addplot[mark=none, color=blue] table [x = $n$, y = $K2$]{data/data.dat};
            \addlegendentry{$F_2$}
            \addplot[mark=none, color=red] table [x = $n$, y = $K3$]{data/data.dat};
            \addlegendentry{$F_3$}
            \addplot[mark=none, color=green] table [x = $n$, y = $K256$]{data/data.dat};
            \addlegendentry{$F_{256}$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Optimum $k$ to minimise complexity}
    \label{graph:k}
\end{figure}
```

The output:
[image: y-axis in terms of 10^x]

How would I get the y-axis to be in terms of 2^x, please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add `ymode=log` and then define the base number with `log basis y={<number>}` in the axis options.

```
    \begin{axis}[ymode=log,log basis y={2},xmin = 0, ymin = 0, scale only axis, height=5cm,
    width=\textwidth, legend pos=north west, xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$k$, width=\textwidth, ]
```

Output (example with other data):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymode=log,log basis y={2},xmin = 0, ymin = 0, scale only axis, height=5cm,
    width=\textwidth, legend pos=north west, xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$k$, width=\textwidth, ]
    \addplot plot coordinates {
    (5,     8.312e-02)
    (17,    2.547e-02)
    (49,    7.407e-03)
    (129,   2.102e-03)
    (321,   5.874e-04)
    (769,   1.623e-04)
    (1793,  4.442e-05)
    (4097,  1.207e-05)
    (9217,  3.261e-06)
    };
    %\addplot[mark=none, color=blue] table [x = $n$, y = $K2$]{data/data.dat};
    %\addlegendentry{$F_2$}
    %\addplot[mark=none, color=red] table [x = $n$, y = $K3$]{data/data.dat};
    %\addlegendentry{$F_3$}
    %\addplot[mark=none, color=green] table [x = $n$, y = $K256$]{data/data.dat};
    %\addlegendentry{$F_{256}$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Optimum $k$ to minimise complexity}
    \label{graph:k}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!